# Automatic task creation based on database condition

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I am new to sharepoint and am having a difficult time on where to start on this one.

I have a database of values(outside of sharepoint).

I wish to check this database each day and if one of the values is over a limit, send a task in sharepoint to an individual based on data in another field in the same row as that value.

From what I can tell I would probably have to populate data inside the sharepoint DB first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through *Business Connectivity Services* and *External Lists*.

Below article might be helpful to you:

1. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-external-list-6e2d601d-b02f-41e7-ba87-e70297ec6665
2. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/make-external-list